# Domain Creation 12.2.1.2.0 ERROR

Tags: weblogic12c, osb, soa-suite

I'm trying to create a standalone domain using QS Templates but I'm facing an error after I configure user, password and port for the domain, the error occurrs during creation time:

> CFGFWK-64254:Error occurred in "OPSS Processing" phase execution.
>       Encountered error:java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>       java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.keySet()Ljava/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap$KeySetView;

I've already configured QS_TEMPLATE variable.

Comment: Google is your friend here: google the error msg and find an Oracle My Oracle Support doc: OPSS - Getting CFGFWK-64254: Error Occurred In "OPSS Processing" Phase Execution during Forms upgrade (Doc ID 2314239.1)  located here: https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?_afrLoop=331114438209960&parent=EXTERNAL_SEARCH&sourceId=PROBLEM&id=2314239.1&_afrWindowMode=0&_adf.ctrl-state=zkffgd903_4

Comment: It's the same problem but in another product: "During Forms domain Upgrade". I tried the last solution since I don't have the domain yet but had no success.

Comment: well, there's clearly a problem with your installation. I suggest posting to the FMW community site for oracle. Or trying a different machine. W/o knowing the machine, OS, JDK versions, etc - which is helpful if you're asking us to take our time to help you debug an install issue ;-) , I can't even begin to guess. Have you tried to create a simple WLS domain? does that work? I assume you verified that your OS, JDK, etc are supported and certified? And of course the exact steps you followed, dirs used, etc.

Comment: there's also a free pre-built SOA Suite virtual box image here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/soasuite/learnmore/vmsoa1213-2660211.html

Comment: No answer on FMW community. Windows 7, jdk1.8.0_51. Simple domain worked. Supported and certified were verified on installation time.I don't wanna use virtual box.

Comment: The error is either due to an incorrect Java version or lack of the JCE libraries present for your JRE (see support link posted by Joe above). Ensure the correct Java version is being used first of all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was because I runned the installer on jdk1.7.0_51 and tried to create the domain on jdk1.8.0_151, after I runned everything on the same version everything worked.